# Docker container with Newrelic Python agent and Supervisord is not sending data

Tags: python, django, docker, newrelic, supervisord

I have a dockerised Django app in uwsgi running using supervisord and I am trying to monitor the app using Newrelic APM. New Relic Python agent installation commands are written inside Dockerfile and in wsgi.py,the below code is included.

```html
import newrelic.agent<br/>
newrelic.agent.initialize('/opt/testapp/newrelic.ini')
```

My supervisord.conf file:

```html
[program:newrelic]<br>
command=newrelic-admin run-program uwsgi --thunder-lock --ini /opt/testapp/uwsgi.ini --protocol http<br>
autostart=true<br>
autorestart=true<br>
redirect_stderr=true
```

Below is my Dockerfile command to copy supervisord conf file and run supervisord

```html
COPY config/supervisord-newrelic.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf <br>
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

After running docker-compose up command, the app gets started and running without any issues, App name is listed in New Relic APM dashboard but not showing any data in my newrelic APM dashboard.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: You shouldn't need to call initialize if you're running through newrelic-admin